# jQuery's animate(); behaviour not as expected(?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
<h1 class="page-title">B<span>eef</span></h1>


jQuery(".page-title").hover(
  function() {

  $(".page-title span").animate({
    width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
  }, "slow"); },

  function() {
    $(".page-title span").animate({
    opacity: 1,
    width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
  }, "slow");
 }
);
```

Given this code, the expected behaviour is that initially I would see "B" as the .page-title. When hovered over, the "eef" should be toggled horizontally in a *swingful* manner. But instead it *pops* up in a very ungraceful way. I have tried different things that seems logic to me to get it smoother, but I am not getting it right.

Oh and:

```
span{
  display: none;
}
```

Trying to mimic this effect: http://susy.oddbird.net/

Any ideas?

Comment: It can be very helpful if you post a http://jsfiddle.net as well as your code so that we can see it in action etc. Also I assume you realise that the site you linked does it with CSS and not jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I got that. However, tried a version with pseudoelements and hovers, but found out that transitions dont work with pseudoelement:hovers - so I ran into a dead end on that one not quite sure how to solve it in a good way. Thus going for an attempt with jQuery. And of course, fiddle me this: http://jsfiddle.net/tomasantonj/GQgRu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span`s are inline elements, so you can't change width of those. Also, you have to hide the overflow. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gronostaj/8hkMG/).

Also, you should consider using CSS3 transitions instead of JavaScript - you'll get smoother animation and your code will be easier to maintain: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gronostaj/qj3PY/).

Comment: Very nice, thank you. What you just said had a mind boggling effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example using jQuery. Instead of implicitly defining a width, you can grab the current width, then set to 0. This way you can animate any length of text. As @gronostaj said, you can't set a width on an inline element so it has to be set to `display:inline-block` & `overflow:hidden`. Also good to add a .stop() so your animations don't go crazy. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/tNkKd/1/)

**jQuery**

```
var spanWidth = $('.page-title span').width();
$('.page-title span').width(0);
$('.page-title').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.page-title span').stop().animate({
            width: spanWidth,
            opacity: 1
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.page-title span').stop().animate({
            width: 0,
            opacity: 0
        });
    }
});​
```

**CSS**

```
h1{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 5em;
}
h1 span{
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```